# Is it possible to list attribute values for one column based on a common attribute value in another column

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select * from categories limit 40;
+--------------+---------------+-----------------+------------
| category_id  | T1            | T2              | T3         
+--------------+---------------+-----------------+------------
             7 | Soft Drinks   | Fountain        | Apple               
            10 | Soft Drinks   | Fountain        | Clear               
            10 | Soft Drinks   | Fountain        | Lemon               
            15 | Soft Drinks   | Tin             | Clear               
            16 | Soft Drinks   | Bottled         | Apple               
            16 | Soft Drinks   | Bottled         | Apple               
            17 | Soft Drinks   | Bottled         | Mango
```

I have 4 columns as shown below ( category_id , T1 , T2 , T3)

How is it possible to group the Data based on T1 ?? (ie Soft Drinks in this case)

For instance a hierarchical structure as shown below

SoftDrinks has three different categories and each category can have sub category with category_id also

```
SoftDrinks ==> Fountain ==> Apple(7) , Clear(10) , Lemon(10) .
SoftDrinks ===> Tin  =====> Clear(15)
SoftDrinks ===> Bottled  =====> Apple(16) , Apple(16) , Mango(17)
```

What is the best way to approach this problem ??

Thanks in advance ??

Comment: The database cannot give you results in any form other than a flat table. You can create the structures you want from this flat table. There's nothing more to be done on the database side.

Comment: Agree , but is it possible to write such a query so that it produces the above requirement ??

Comment: I can't tell what the above requirement is. If you can write it in a flat table form, it's possible to write a query. If you can't, it's not possible.

Comment: @Devon , i am not getting category_d with the query you meantioned , do i need to chnage anything ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select t1, t2, group_concat(concat(t3,'(',cateogoryId,')'),', ') x

from something

group by 1,2
```

Comment: And if you want to have '==> ' also, just concat all the columns with intermediate ' ==> '

Comment: Thanks , i have tried with the above query its giving me sql syntax error , i am using mysql 5.5 .could you please help

Comment: @Kiran. You have a 1000 rep and yet you don't know what to do with a syntax error. I can't believe it.

Comment: I don't have access to MySQL right now:
Can you try :
select t1, t2, group_concat(t3,', ',cateogoryId,', ') group by 1,2

Comment: @jacobjonz , Thank you very much , you have completed my work .

Comment: The `concat()` is unnecessary.  `group_concat()` will accept multiple string arguments.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, Noticed that. I have it added as one of the comments.